# How to report a series of ANOVA results in a paper?

Tags: anova, reporting

I have five 1x3 ANOVA with post hoc Tukey's test. I think it is quite boring to repeat the same sentences five times. It's possible (in APA style) to summarize the results in a table and just report the comment on the results in the text?